# Multiple SQL Case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please help me in Writing the script to select records in the below format(attached an image). Only flags are stored in the database. Other column should be hard coded based on the flag selection. I have created a script for that and its working, but i would like to know if there is better way to do this. This should be done in SQL Server 2012

**Result:**

[image]

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (Flag1 INT,Flag2 INT,Flag3 INT,Flag4 INT,Flag5 INT,Name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,0,0,0,0,'aaa'),(0,1,0,0,0,'bbb'),(0,0,1,0,0,'ccc'),(0,0,0,1,0,'ddd'),(1,0,0,0,1,'eee'),
(1,0,0,1,0,'fff'),(0,1,0,1,0,'ggg'),(0,0,1,0,0,'hhh'),(0,0,0,0,1,'iii'),(0,0,0,0,1,'jjj')

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col3_item1' END col3, 
        CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col4_item1' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col3_item1' END col3, 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col4_item1' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col3_item2' END col3,           
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col4_item2' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col3_item3' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col4_item3' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col3_item4' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col4_item4' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col3_item1' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col4_item1' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col3_item2' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col4_item2' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col3_item3' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col4_item3' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col3_item4' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col4_item4' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id4_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id4_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id4_col3_item1' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id4_col4_item1' END col4 FROM @temp

        UNION ALL 

SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id5_col1_item1' END col1 , 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id5_col2_item1' END col2, 
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id5_col3_item1' END col3,
        CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id5_col4_item1' END col4 FROM @temp
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Some more information is needed - what are you writing the script in and why? What have you already written (you say it is working)? Perhaps Code Review would be more appropriate - but we would need to see the script itself to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

> I have modified It as sql server, Try This...

```
 SELECT isnull(Flag1,'') Flag1, isnull(Flag2,'') Flag2, isnull(Flag3,'')
 Flag3, isnull(Flag4,'') Flag4, isnull(Flag5,'') Flag5, 
 (CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col1_item1' ELSE 
 CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col1_item1' ELSE  
 CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col1_item1' 
 ELSE  '' 
 END) AS col1,
 (CASE WHEN flag1=1 THEN 'Id1_col2_item1' ELSE 
 CASE WHEN flag2=1 THEN 'Id2_col2_item1' ELSE  
 CASE WHEN flag3=1 THEN 'Id3_col2_item1' 
 ELSE  '' 
 END) AS col2,
 ..........................
 ..........................
 FROM @temp;
```

Comment: Thank you! but that solution wont work. Please see the table format for result set.

Comment: On which RDBMS you are running this query as you haven't mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Sql Server 2012

Comment: I have modified It as for sql server